# OpenGL Failed to link program pipeline: Vertex info (Upon changing my computer

Tags: c++, opengl, error-handling, glsl

Recently I changed my computer and that was the only thing that broke OpenGL rendering in my software. All my shapes turn black; it won't take uniform inputs as well (such as view matrix), because apaprently the ProgramPipeline won't link.

Both my vertex/fragment shaders compile well but glLinkProgramgives off this error:

```
Failed to link program pipeline: Vertex info 
error C7592: ARB_separate_shader_objects requires built-in block gl_PerVertex to be redeclared before accessing its members.
```

I narrowed it down a bit more with glGetError, and it specifically gave off errorcode 1281 after `glUseProgramStages(mPipeline, GL_VERTEX_SHADER_BIT, mVert->shader())`.

I did attempt to declare the gl_PerVertex block as below but the error persists and now it won't draw anything.

```
#version 460
#extension GL_ARB_separate_shader_objects: enable

in vec2 vPosition2D;
in vec4 v8Color;

uniform mat4 uView;

out vec4 fColor;
out gl_PerVertex {
    vec4 gl_Position;
};

void main() {
    gl_Position = uView * vec4(vPosition2D, 0.0, 1.0);
    fColor = v8Color;
}
```

The following is the entirety of the glew code, attempting to link successfully compiled vertex/fragment shaders into a single ProgramPipeline:

```
glGenVertexArrays(1, &mVao);
glBindVertexArray(mVao);
glGenBuffers(1, &mVbo);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mVbo);
mVert->vertexAttribPointer();
mVert->enableVertexAttribArray();
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mTargetCount * mVert->size(), 0, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

glGenBuffers(1, &mIbo);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, mIbo);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, mTargetCount * 8 * sizeof(uint), 0, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

glGenProgramPipelines(1, &mPipeline);
glBindProgramPipeline(mPipeline);
glProgramParameteri(mPipeline, GL_PROGRAM_SEPARABLE, GL_TRUE);
glUseProgramStages(mPipeline, GL_VERTEX_SHADER_BIT, mVert->shader());
glUseProgramStages(mPipeline, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER_BIT, mFrag->shader());
glLinkProgram(mPipeline);
GLint status;
glGetProgramiv(mPipeline, GL_LINK_STATUS, &status);
if (status == GL_FALSE) {
    GLint maxLength = 0;
    glGetProgramiv(mPipeline, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &maxLength);
    std::vector<char> errorLog(maxLength);
    glGetProgramInfoLog(mPipeline, maxLength, &maxLength, &errorLog[0]);

    std::string errorMessage(errorLog.begin(), errorLog.end());
    std::cout << "Failed to link program pipeline: " << errorMessage << std::endl;
}
```

I'm 98% sure it's not any issue of passing variables, such as binding/pointer/enabling attribs. I quadruple-checked to see if there were any mistakes of that sort: not only were there none, but there shouldn't be considering I changed nothing from which worked fine in my previous computer.

Obviously it's the OpenGL version upgrade that's the culprit. Did the workings of OpenGL Program Pipeline somehow change? My graphics driver is up to date and checked that it's version 4.6.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up debugging with APITrace... and had the issue and solution be the exact same: error C7592.

And now apparently it works, everything else the same?... I did insert the entire block instead of just gl_Position, for those who might have had the same issue.

```
out gl_PerVertex {
  vec4 gl_Position;
  float gl_PointSize;
  float gl_ClipDistance[];
};
```